# How to make edges of adjacent objects be visible?

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders

On the picture below I have planes inside of the other plane, but borders of all these planes disappear visually in Look Dev mode. But I need separate planes to be distinct.
I'm not talking about Blender view settings, but about shaders, materials...
I need borders of planes be darker. Like they were in Solid mode.
[image]
[image]

Comment: it's very hard to understand what's your object and what's your problem, please give more details, perhaps share your file

Comment: @moonboots done.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very imprecise, but if you want to see the grooves on the hull you could do it this way:

- Join all your objects into one, merge the vertices by distance.
- Select the edges that are supposed to become grooves.
- Bevel them.
- Give some correction in order to have nice grooves (my version needs to be re-worked in order to have a proper topology because it will mess up once you'll give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier.
- Extrude.

[image]